# Sorting an Array with HeapSort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, heapsort

We have to sort an Array with random numbers. For this, we need to use this part of code ( HeapSort )

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HeapSort<E extends Comparable<E>> {   
    public ArrayList<E> h;
    public int SIZE;
    public int n;

public HeapSort(int s){
    SIZE=s;
    n=1;
    h=new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        h.add(null);
}

public void Insert(E e){
    h.set(n,e);
    n++;
    // swapping up
    if(n!=2){           // more than 1 element
        int s=n-1;      // last added element 
        int p=s/2;      // its parent
        while(s!=1 && LT(s,p)){
            swap(p,s);
            s=p;
            p=p/2;
        }
    }
}

public boolean Empty(){
    return n==1;
}

public E Lesser(){
    return h.get(1);
}

public void Delete(){
    n--;
    h.set(1,h.get(n));  // last element to the root
    h.set(n,null);
    // swapping down
    int ip=1;
    int ils=2;
    int irs=3;
    while(ConditionSwapDown(ip,ils,irs)){
        if(Exists(ils) && Exists(irs)){
            // two sons
            if(LT(ils,ip) || LT(irs,ip)){
                // at least one child is lesser than the parent -> swap
                if(LT(ils,irs)){
                    swap(ip,ils);   // swapping down left
                    ip=ils;
                    ils=ip*2;
                    irs=ils+1;
                }
                else{
                    swap(ip,irs);   // swapping down right
                    ip=irs;
                    ils=ip*2;
                    irs=ils+1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            // only left son
            if(Exists(ils) && !Exists(irs)){
                if(LT(ils,ip)){     // left son is lesser than the parent
                    swap(ip,ils);
                    ip=ils;
                    ils=ip*2;
                    irs=ils+1;
                }
            }
            // else no children and end of swapping down
    }
}

public boolean ConditionSwapDown(int p,int l,int r){
    // (has 2 children and (parent>left or parent>right)) or
    // (has 1 children and parent>left)
    return (((Exists(l) && Exists(r)) && (LT(l,p) || LT(r,p)))) ||
    (Exists(l) && !Exists(r) && LT(l,p));
}

public boolean Exists(int p){
    if(p>=SIZE)
        return false;
    return h.get(p)!=null;
}

public void swap(int a,int b){
    E c=h.get(a);
    h.set(a,h.get(b));
    h.set(b,c);
}

public boolean LT(int a,int b){     // h[a]<h[b]
    return h.get(a).compareTo(h.get(b))<0;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String r="";
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        r+=h.get(i)+" ";
    return r;
}

public String Print(){
    return PrintR(1,"");
}
public String PrintR(int i,String p){
    String r=p+h.get(i)+"\n";
    if(h.get(i*2)!=null || h.get(i*2+1)!=null){
        if(h.get(i*2)!=null)
            r+=PrintR(i*2,p+"   ");
        else
            r+=p+"   -\n";
        if(h.get(i*2+1)!=null)
            r+=PrintR(i*2+1,p+"   ");
        else
            r+=p+"   -\n";
    }
    return r;
}
```

How do we "connect" the two codes? or use our array with HeapSort? For the Array we have done this:

```
public class P3 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
   System.out.println("Quina llargada tindrà la taula? ");
   int n = reader.nextInt(); //n=llargada taula
   int[] taula = new int[n];


   int fi = 100*n;
   Random rand = new Random();
   //int al = rand.nextInt(fi) + 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < taula.length; i++) 
       taula[i] = rand.nextInt(fi);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taula)); }}
```

Comment: Side note: you should stick to the Java code conventions, e.g. method names that start with a lower case character to avoid confusion between methods and classes or their constructors. Besides that, what's the problem with feeding your array to the `HeapSort` instance or reading the sorted array/list back (or doing it in place)?

Comment: Have you tried using that class?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in the `HeapSort` class, waiting for you to use it:

```
    int[] taula = {4, 2, 8, 1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(taula));

    // 'heapSort' variable will store ordered list
    HeapSort<Integer> heapSort = new HeapSort<>(taula.length+1);

    for (Integer i : taula)
        heapSort.Insert(i);

    System.out.println(heapSort);
```